# Azure Mobile Service Custom API not updating

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

Has anyone using ZUMO experienced the following?

Calling a Custom API gives you x set of logs according to what ever is in your code.
I've updated the code and I still get those log entries but they don't even exist in code..
Deleted the API, I can still call it? and get the same log entries, it's like it's cached or something has broke...

Any ideas how I can do a platform reset or something?

Thanks.

Si

Comment: To add fuel to the fire, that initial API is showing as deleted yet I can still call it, I created a new Custom API, same code and I see IO errors when calling it, this makes me assume from client to azure it can't find it...it's like i'm hitting the wrong thing on azure.  Absolutely nothing has changed.

Comment: Looks like some sort of bug in Mobile Services, switching the schema from dynamic, saving and then back again will recycle the ZUMO instance, that's the workaround.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the custom API of our mobile services. Started happening last Friday. Just tried changing the dynamic schema change and back and seems to work. But I cannot say for sure that is what fixed it, although worth a try.